# How can I save a value (task) inside a variable name ref in real time database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to save a 'task' in real time database, and I want it to save inside the account name ref. And it's getting outside the name of the user.

[image: the task outside the user]

Function that saves the task:

```
function savetask() {

  var task = input.value;
  //* ENVIA O VALOR DO INPUT (task)  ASSOCIADO AO NOME RECOLHIDO  A CIMA PARA A DATABASE DA FIREBASE
  firebase.database().ref('nomes').push(
    task
  );
  console.log('A seguinte tarefa foi enviada para a database:', task)

}
inputnota.addEventListener('submit', savetask)
```

Function that saves the name in the database :

```
function savename(nome) {
    var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
    //* save in database
    firebase.database().ref('nomes').child(nome).push({
        'nome:':nome
    });
    console.log('teu nome:',nome)
    alert('Welcome:',nome)

    //* prevent form from submitting
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `nome` in this code fragment:

```
firebase.database().ref('nomes').push(
  task
);
```

So to make it write to the same path, you need:

```
firebase.database().ref('nomes').child('salsa').push(
  task
);
```

Or reading the `nome` from the HTML as you do in the other code block already:

```
var nome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
firebase.database().ref('nomes').child(nome).push(
  task
);
```

Comment: The thing is i would  want it to add to the variable nome not only the 'salsa' and the code is from two different files. So i don't really know if it is possible

Comment: And i did the second exaample and i get the error :child failed:path argument was an invalid path = "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Comment: So it sounds like your `nome` is undefined in that file. If the second code snippet is on a different page, you will have to pass the relevant value from the first to the second page. This is unrelated to Firebase, so I recommend searching for something like: [how to pass a value from one HTML page to another](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+pass+a+value+from+one+HTML+page+to+another)